# How to set different different text colour for each cell in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to set a different background color for each cell in the `UICollectionViewCell`.

[image: UICollectionView Screenshot]

1. Text should be in different colour.like(one=red, two=green like
   wise).
2. I want the last cell "select all" I want this cell without
3. any shadow effect. Only **See All** Should be in centre.

Comment: What your code in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`? Put some logic there.

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried?

Comment: @hd1344 Can you please share the code??
for different text color, in cellForItemAtindexPath: you need to pass different color for different index.
Ex - if(indexPath.row == 1){//pass text color here}

Comment: lets see your code section

Answer (score 1):

In order to set a random text color for each cell you can first create a function to generate random colors like this.

```
- (UIColor *)getRandomColor {
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    UIColor *randomColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
    return randomColor;
}
```

then inside the `-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you can set the color to the text label like so

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     // you can do it inside the cell's subclass file also, which might be better
     cell.titleLabel.textColor = [self getRandomColor]; 
     cell.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


    // as for question 3
    // quick way to achieve this would be to check if its the last row 
    // and set the text alignment to center.
    // but calling `count` for every cell has a performance hit
    // so you can save it into a variable outside the delegate

    if (indexPath.row == [dataArray count] - 1]) {
       cell.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to provide specific color on each index cell then you can provide switch case and apply the color to text in -(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method otherwise use random color by calling some function to get random color .

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the OP's question